# Android process killed; is this log a normal "killed process"- log (no uncaught exception?)

Tags: android, multithreading

I have an Android app which consists of a service running 4 threads. I don't *think* that there is one of the threads crashing (see further). But I see that the app is killed : it seems to just vanish !

---

My process had pid 26580. At some point in time (see 12:11:29.440), I get a log message from Android : **killProcessQuiet**. Shortly thereafter (same timestamp, a couple of log messages further),
ActivityManager mentions : "No longer want phb.myapp (pid 26580)" and yet another message (at 12:11:29.450) : "Recipient 26580".

In the end, the last mention I see of my app is from ActivityManager a last time (at 12:11:29.460) : "Scheduling restart of **crashed** service phb.myapp/.GPSLoggerService in 5000ms"

After this my process is never heard of any more. Note that at present I don't want to return START_STICKY from onStartCommand, because I am still troubleshooting the app. Even if it is a possible solution (which in the end, I realise, I will have to do to keep it running), I want to make sure that there isn't *some* uncaught exception. How can I be sure there isn't ? I hope that if there isn't any trace of any exception in the Android system log, that I may be sure of this ? On the other hand, why does the log mention "**crashed**" service ?

(I have saved the complete log, in case there's more information needed from it for possible answers)

---

The (extracted part of the) system log hereafter :

> ```
> ...
> 09-09 12:10:24.050: D/phb.myapp.GPSPositionLoggerThread(26580): onLocationChanged()
> 09-09 12:10:24.050: D/PowerManagerService(383): releaseWakeLock(41e5a960): PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK , tag=GCoreFlp, flags=0x1
> 09-09 12:10:24.060: D/AutoSetting(30943): service - mHandler: request passive update
> 09-09 12:10:24.060: D/AutoSetting(30943): service - handleMessage() incoming message, what:1
> 09-09 12:10:24.060: D/phb.myapp.GPSPositionStreamerThread(26580): _handleThreadMessage(STREAM_POSITION)
> ...
> 09-09 12:11:29.440: D/Process(383): killProcessQuiet, pid=26580
> 09-09 12:11:29.440: D/Process(383): dalvik.system.VMStack.getThreadStackTrace(Native Method)
> 09-09 12:11:29.440: D/Process(383): java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:599)
> 09-09 12:11:29.440: D/Process(383): android.os.Process.killProcessQuiet(Process.java:986)
> 09-09 12:11:29.440: D/Process(383): com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.updateOomAdjLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:16273)
> 09-09 12:11:29.440: D/Process(383): com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.updateOomAdjLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:16176)
> 09-09 12:11:29.440: D/Process(383): com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.serviceDoneExecutingLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:13658)
> 09-09 12:11:29.440: D/Process(383): com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.serviceDoneExecuting(ActivityManagerService.java:13628)
> 09-09 12:11:29.440: D/Process(383): android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:788)
> 09-09 12:11:29.440: D/Process(383): com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:1887)
> 09-09 12:11:29.440: D/Process(383): android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:367)
> 09-09 12:11:29.440: D/Process(383): dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
> 09-09 12:11:29.440: I/ActivityManager(383): No longer want phb.myapp (pid 26580): hidden #16, adj=15
> 09-09 12:11:29.450: D/GpsLocationProvider(383): GPS status listener died
> 09-09 12:11:29.450: D/CarGpsProvider(383): GPS Mock status listener died
> 09-09 12:11:29.450: V/LocationManagerService(383): Location listener died
> 09-09 12:11:29.450: I/ActivityManager(383): Recipient 26580
> ...
> 09-09 12:11:29.460: V/GpsLocationProvider(383): enableLocationTracking ++
> 09-09 12:11:29.460: D/GpsLocationProvider(383): [handleMessage] message :9
> 09-09 12:11:29.460: D/GpsLocationProvider(383): [handleMessage] REMOVE_LISTENER
> 09-09 12:11:29.460: W/GpsLocationProvider(383): Unneeded remove listener for android.uid.system:1000
> 09-09 12:11:29.460: D/GpsLocationProvider(383): [handleMessage] message :3
> 09-09 12:11:29.460: D/GpsLocationProvider(383): [handleMessage] ENABLE_TRACKING
> 09-09 12:11:29.460: D/GpsLocationProvider(383): stopNavigating
> 09-09 12:11:29.460: D/GpsLocationProvider(383): stopNavigating: native_stop+
> 09-09 12:11:29.460: V/LocationManagerService(383): _removeUpdates: listener = Receiver{41eca188 Listener android.os.BinderProxy@4127a9f0}mUpdateRecords: {gps=UpdateRecord {41e50d10 mProvider: gps mUid: 10206}}
> 09-09 12:11:29.460: W/ActivityManager(383): Scheduling restart of crashed service phb.myapp/.GPSLoggerService in 5000ms
> ...
> 09-09 12:11:30.870: I/THERMAL_GET_TEMP(143): Read adc from PROC_COMM: 1519
> 09-09 12:11:30.870: I/THERMAL_GET_TEMP(143): Adc: 1519, Millidegree Celsius: 34540
> 09-09 12:11:35.870: I/THERMAL_GET_TEMP(143): Read adc from PROC_COMM: 1539
> 09-09 12:11:35.870: I/THERMAL_GET_TEMP(143): Adc: 1539, Millidegree Celsius: 33521
> 09-09 12:11:40.870: I/THERMAL_GET_TEMP(143): Read adc from PROC_COMM: 1539
> 09-09 12:11:40.870: I/THERMAL_GET_TEMP(143): Adc: 1539, Millidegree Celsius: 33521
> ```

And the log of my app :

```
09-09 12:05:14.050: D/phb.myapp.GPSPositionLoggerThread(26580): onLocationChanged()
09-09 12:05:14.050: D/phb.myapp.GPSPositionStreamerThread(26580): _handleThreadMessage(STREAM_POSITION)
09-09 12:06:02.050: D/phb.myapp.GPSPositionLoggerThread(26580): onLocationChanged()
09-09 12:06:02.070: D/phb.myapp.GPSPositionStreamerThread(26580): _handleThreadMessage(STREAM_POSITION)
09-09 12:07:41.070: D/phb.myapp.GPSPositionLoggerThread(26580): onLocationChanged()
09-09 12:07:41.080: D/phb.myapp.GPSPositionStreamerThread(26580): _handleThreadMessage(STREAM_POSITION)
09-09 12:08:43.060: D/phb.myapp.GPSPositionLoggerThread(26580): onLocationChanged()
09-09 12:08:43.060: D/phb.myapp.GPSPositionStreamerThread(26580): _handleThreadMessage(STREAM_POSITION)
09-09 12:09:29.070: D/phb.myapp.GPSPositionLoggerThread(26580): onLocationChanged()
09-09 12:09:29.070: D/phb.myapp.GPSPositionStreamerThread(26580): _handleThreadMessage(STREAM_POSITION)
09-09 12:10:24.050: D/phb.myapp.GPSPositionLoggerThread(26580): onLocationChanged()
09-09 12:10:24.060: D/phb.myapp.GPSPositionStreamerThread(26580): _handleThreadMessage(STREAM_POSITION)
```

(after which the app is dead)

Comment: its all logcat ... can I please see some part of the code ^_^

Comment: It's hard to put all the code. Exactly what would you like to see ?

Comment: Is the app visible at the time? Is the service running in the foreground? If not, guaranteed it will be shut down.

Comment: The app doesn't have a visible interface : it is a background service. It just has one preference screen. I have no problem if it disappears, I know I can restart it by returning START_STICKY from onStartCommand. But I just want to make sure it doesn't crash because of some missed exception catch ...

Comment: Have you wakelocked your service?

Comment: There's no wakelock (yet), as I want to first make sure that I handle this siuation properly. A wakelock, as of now, would rather prevent me retriggering this situation. And then, I would still not be sure of my issue (being : this really IS Android which kills my app, isn't it ?) Only when I'm sure of this will I insert more features like a wakelock. Because a wakelock wouldn't prevent me from running into this situation later either, to my feeling...